# merge /discard reports 'No Pending Changes' when /candidate shows them

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

I'm trying to run a `merge /discard` command (`tfs merge /discard /version:nnn:yyy $/sourceproj $/targetproj /recursive`) but it says there are no pending changes.

If I run a `tfs merge /candidate $/sourceproj $/targetproj` it shows the relevant changesets as candidates.

any ideas why this happens and how to get round it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact changeset number try:

tf merge /discard /version:C111~C111 BranchX BranchY /recursive

This assumes you know the changeset number (in this case 111).

If that doesn't work, then can you update your question to give the exact values you are entering along with the output for the candidate check?

Comment: Hi,

The exact command is:

tf merge /discard /version:26355~32983 $/systems/dev/translations $/systems/test/Translations /recursive

The output from the candidate command is huge but contains the above list plus a few either side of the range.

Comment: try with a preface of C:  tf merge /discard /version:C26355~C32983 $/systems/dev/translations $/systems/test/Translations /recursive  I would also try using just one changeset instead of the range to verify you can at least do that so try, after doing what I just suggested assuming it doesn't work, tf merge /discard /version:C26355~C26355 $/systems/dev/translations $/systems/test/Translations /recursive

Comment: Thanks for the info.
Doing the range with the C preface worked but only on one  changeset at a time. I have absolutely loads to do so doing them individually isn't really an option.
Very odd.

Comment: My guess would be there is an issue with one of the changesets between the range if in fact you can't get it to work with C26355~C32983 and you are positive that you have all those changesets available.  If you are trying to sync up two branches another option is to do a baseless discard merge assuming it was a dev to main scenario.  I would need to know a little more about your scenario but yes it seems odd that you can't use the version range and you can use one version.

Answer (score 0):

You may have cloaked/not mapped some of the target paths that are affected by the merge candidate. As there is no file that could be checked out for the merge, those files will ignored, resulting in the strange behaviour.
Consider this structure:

```
/branch-A
   /SomeFolder
   /OtherFolder
/branch-Main
   /SomeFolder
   /OtherFolder [CLOAKED]
```

When the changeset contains `/branch-A/SomeFolder` and `/branch-A/OtherFolder` and you try to merge from branch-A to branch-Main in this workspace, only `SomeFolder` will be merged, resulting in a partial merge of the changeset and thus appearing again as candidate. You will never be able to merge (or merge/discard) the changes for OtherFolder until you map `/branch-Main/OtherFolder` in your workspace.

BTW: Generally only the merge TARGET paths must be mapped in a workspace when merging, so you could very well merge `/branch-Main/OtherFolder` to `/branch-A/OtherFolder` in the sample workspace above.

Comment: please, could you suggest a workaround to solve the "cloaked folder" issue?

Comment: @constructor sorry, there seems not to be a good solution. Mine was to have a second Workspace that only Maps the complete *target* branch without any cloaking and use that one for merging.
meanwhile, we switched to git :)